# Title page with a colored band from right side

Tags: eso-pic

I have in my file this command which creates a colored band in my page title from left to right, but restricted to 33% of the page. How could I add a similar effect but to right side of the title page; so, two bands in both sides and white in the middle.

```
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{Blue}\rule{.33\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Title Page
\title{Colourful Bands\\ on titlepage}
\author{My Self}

\date{}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{Blue}\rule{.33\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
\hspace*{0.34\paperwidth}
  \color{DarkGreen}\rule{.33\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin = 0pt}
    \maketitle

\restoregeometry
\chapter{Chapter Title}
%
chapter text.

\end{document}
```

[image]